# Sitecore Export/transfer the content tree

Tags: sitecore, data-migration

What if a user has sitecore on two machines. And he wants to copy a "content tree" or any other item from one machine to the other machine. What will be the procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be few ways how to do it:

1. [Create package](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/package_designer_admin_guide-a4.pdf) 
   You should create package on one Sitecore and then install it on another.
2. Serialize items.
   You can serialize items, copy serialization from serialization folder of one Sitecore to another one and deserialize items.
3. Use 3rd party tools, e.g. [Unicorn](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn), [Razl](https://www.hhogdev.com/products/razl.aspx).